# In Angular, is there a way to change a certain variable's value when the page loads?

Tags: html, angular, angular5, frontend

I have a navigation bar with 3 anchor tags. When an anchor tag is clicked, certain components associated with it are visible; while components associated with other anchor tags are hidden. (i.e. only one is active at a time) My issue is that the components only get displayed when you click an item in the nav bar. ((click)="...")
Is there a way to initialize a='Y' on load of the page? (Without using JavaScript)

```
  <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" (click)="a='Y'; b='N'; c='N'">Title a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" (click)="a='N'; b='Y'; c='N'">Title b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" (click)="a='N'; b='N'; c='Y'">Title c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

<ng-container *ngIf = "a==='Y'"> {some of a's components here....} </ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf = "b==='Y'"> {some of b's components here....} </ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf = "c==='Y'"> {some of c's components here....} </ng-container>
```

Comment: Did you try [`ngOnInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit#ngoninit)?

Answer (score 1):

What you do here goes against the best practices of Angular.

See angular routing: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Also, why not put any initialization code in the controller?